# How are movies chosen for the MTV Movie Awards?

Tags: awards, mtv

Every year MTV hosts the MTV Movie Awards.  How are the movies nominated, what movies **can be** nominated, and how are the winners chosen?

Answer (score 3):

From [MTV Movie Awards wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTV_Movie_Awards), it says-

> The nominees are decided by producers and executives at MTV. Winners
>   are decided online by the general public. Presently voting is done
>   through MTV's official website through a special Movie Awards link at
>   [movieawards.mtv.com](http://movieawards.mtv.com/).

Comment: ok, but what movies can be nominated?